# Handling one to one relationship between django models

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I am having a one to one relationship between 2 models. While creating the second model, I want to pass the instance of the first model to the second one.

These 2 models are new tabs/features in our web application. I tried passing the instance through URL but didn't succeed. Maybe I am not following steps correctly.

Details about:

python version: Python 3.6.4 :: Anaconda, Inc.

django version: 2.0.2-3

Please find below the code:

1) models.py

```py
class StudyConcept(models.Model):
    requestor_name = models.CharField(max_length=240, blank=False, null=False)
    project = models.CharField(max_length=240, blank=False, null=False)
    date_of_request = models.DateField(blank=False, null=False)
    brief_summary = models.CharField(max_length=4000, blank=False, null=False)

    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)

class Logistics(models.Model):
    budget = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False, null=False)
    business_technology = models.CharField(max_length=3, choices=CHOICES, blank=False, null=False)
    vendor_or_contracts = models.CharField(max_length=3, choices=CHOICES, blank=False, null=False)

    studyConcept = models.OneToOneField(StudyConcept, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('update_Logistics', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})


    def get_deliverablesLogistics(self):
        return ','.join([str(i) for i in self.deliverablesLogistics.all().values_list('id', flat=True)])

    def get_paymentScheduleLogistics(self):
        return ','.join([str(i) for i in self.paymentScheduleLogistics.all().values_list('id', flat=True)])

    def get_commentsLogistics(self):
        return ','.join([str(i) for i in self.commentsLogistics.all().values_list('id', flat=True)])


class DeliverablesLogistics(models.Model):
    milestone_deliverable = models.CharField('MileStone/Deliverable', max_length=480, blank=False, null=False)
    poa = models.CharField('POA', max_length=480, blank=False, null=False)
    start_date = models.DateField(blank=False, null=False)
    end_date = models.DateField(blank=False, null=False)
    logistics = models.ForeignKey(Logistics, related_name='deliverablesLogistics', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)


class PaymentScheduleLogistics(models.Model):
    milestone_deliverable = models.CharField('MileStone/Deliverable', max_length=480, blank=False, null=False)
    cost = models.DecimalField(max_digits=14, decimal_places=2, blank=False, null=False, default=0)
    estimated_payment_date = models.DateField(blank=False, null=False)
    logistics = models.ForeignKey(Logistics, related_name='paymentScheduleLogistics', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)
class CommentsLogistics(models.Model):
    comments = models.CharField('Comment', max_length=2000, blank=True, null=True)
    commented_by = models.CharField(max_length=2000, blank=True, null=True)
    logistics = models.ForeignKey(Logistics, related_name='commentsLogistics', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)
```

2. views.py

```py
def load_concepts(request):
    currentUser = User.objects.get(id=request.user.id)
    concepts = StudyConcept.objects.all().filter(user=request.user)
    #concepts = get_object_or_404(StudyConcept)
    return render(request, 'concept_dropdown_list_options.html',{
        'concepts':concepts
    })

class LogisticsFormsetCreate(CreateView):
    model = Logistics
    template_name = 'createLogistics.html'
    form_class = LogisticsForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('create_Logistics')

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        data = super(LogisticsFormsetCreate, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        if self.request.POST:
            data['deliverable'] = DeliverablesLogisticsFormset(self.request.POST, prefix='deliverables')
            data['paymentSchedule'] = PaymentScheduleLogisticsFormset(self.request.POST, prefix='payments')
            data['comment'] = CommentsLogisticsFormset(self.request.POST, prefix='comments')
            #data['studyRequestConcept'] = self.request.POST.get('studyRequestConcept')

        else:
            data['deliverable'] = DeliverablesLogisticsFormset(prefix='deliverables')
            data['paymentSchedule'] = PaymentScheduleLogisticsFormset(prefix='payments')
            data['comment'] = CommentsLogisticsFormset(prefix='comments')
            #data['studyRequestConcept'] = self.request.GET.get('studyRequestConcept')
        return data

    def form_valid(self, form):
        context = self.get_context_data()
        deliverable = context['deliverable'] 
        paymentSchedule = context['paymentSchedule']
        comment = context['comment']
        with transaction.atomic():
            if deliverable.is_valid() and paymentSchedule.is_valid() and comment.is_valid():
                self.object = form.save(commit=False)
                self.object.user = self.request.user
                self.object = form.save()
                deliverable.instance = self.object
                deliverable.save()
                paymentSchedule.instance = self.object
                paymentSchedule.save()
                comment.instance = self.object
                comment.save()
                messages.success(self.request, Logistics.__name__ +' Form ID: '+ str(self.object.id) + ' was submitted successfully')
                return super(LogisticsFormsetCreate, self).form_valid(form)
            else:
                return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data(form=form))
```

3. Template

```html
{% extends "header.html" %}
{% load widget_tweaks %}
{% block content %}
{% csrf_token %}

{% include 'xdsoft_stylesheets.html' %}

{% include 'messages.html' %}
<div class="container" align="center">
    <h1 class="display-5">Logistics</h1>
</div>
<br/>

<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered" id="example" data-toggle="table"
    data-filter-control="true" data-show-export="true"
    data-click-to-select="true" data-toolbar="#toolbar" data-escape>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th class="text-center" data-field="id" data-filter-control="input">ID</th>
                <th class="text-center" data-field="project" data-filter-control="input">Project</th>
                <th class="text-center" data-field="date_of_request" data-filter-control="input">Date</th>
                <th class="text-center" data-field="brief_summary" data-filter-control="input">Summary</th>
                <th class="text-center" data-field="scientific_question" data-filter-control="input">Question</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            {%for studyRequestConcept in concepts %}
            <tr>
                <td style="width:200px">
                    <a class=" btn btn-primary js-create-logistics" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal" href="{% url 'create_Logistics' %}">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
                        New Logistics
                    </a>
                </td>
                <td class="text-left">{{studyRequestConcept.id}}</td>
                <td class="text-left">{{studyRequestConcept.project}}</td>
                <td class="text-left">{{studyRequestConcept.date_of_request}}</td>
                <td class="text-left">{{studyRequestConcept.brief_summary}}</td>
                <td class="text-left">{{studyRequestConcept.scientific_question}}</td>
            </tr>
            {% endfor%}
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>

{% comment %}The modal container{% endcomment %}
<div class="modal" id="modal" data-backdrop="false"></div>

<script>
    $(function () {
        $('.js-create-logistics').click( function () {
            var btn = $(this)
            $.ajax({
                url: btn.attr("href"),
                context: document.body
            }).done(function(response) {
                $("#modal").html(response);
            });
        });
    });
</script>

{% endblock %}
```

I have a view/template where I list all the Study Concepts and every row has a create new Logistics button next to it. After clicking create new logistics button, the modal/view will open that will allow you to create a new Logistics. I want to pass the instance of the object study concept when I click the button.

Also, CreateLogistics is a class-based view designed using "from django.views.generic import CreateView"

I will be more than happy to provide any further code or information needed. Thanks in advance for all the support and help.

Regards,

Amey Kelekar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't shown your URLs, but you need to accept the ID in the URL for the CreateView and use it in `form_valid`. For example:

```
path('/create_logistics/<int:id>/', LogisticsFormsetCreate.as_view(), name="create_Logistics"),
```

So in the template you would do:

```
<a class="btn btn-primary js-create-logistics" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal" href="{% url 'create_Logistics' id=studyRequestConcept.id %}">
```

and in the view:

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    ...
    self.object = form.save(commit=False)
    self.object.user = self.request.user
    self.object.studyConcept_id = self.kwargs['id']
    self.object.save()
    ...
```

Comment: Hi @Daniel, My URL code is 

re_path(r'^createLogistics/$', login_required(views.LogisticsFormsetCreate.as_view()), name='create_Logistics'),


But I will try to implement my code as explained by you.

Regards,

Comment: Hi @Daniel, I am getting this error after doing your changes: "Reverse for 'create_Logistics' with keyword arguments '{'id': 1}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['createLogistics/<int:id>/$']". I have updated my url pattern to "re_path(r'^createLogistics/<int:id>/$', login_required(views.LogisticsFormsetCreate.as_view()), name='create_Logistics'),". Please let me know if i have followed anything incorrectly. Regards, Amey Kelekar

Comment: My example used `path`, not `re_path`.

Comment: I have updated re_path to the path and did the necessary changes, but still, when I input all the values and try to create a new logistics, it gives me the following error: "Reverse for 'create_Logistics' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['createLogistics\\/(?P<id>[0-9]+)\\/$']"

Comment: Hi @Daniel, your solution worked, I just had to change success_url = reverse_lazy('load_concepts'). Thank you for your help and support